# Rails App Failing in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have just deployed my Rails app to Heroku using git (git push heroku master).
However I just get the message:"We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information." Here is the logfile:

```
2015-04-08T20:58:32.525530+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 15d1bce by karlneumann61@gmail.com
2015-04-08T20:58:32.525530+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v33 created by karlneumann61@gmail.com
2015-04-08T20:58:58.387070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2015-04-08T20:58:58.387070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2015-04-08T20:59:01.918413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 19263 -e production`
2015-04-08T20:59:05.853782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-04-08T20:59:05.711368+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-08 20:59:05] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-02-25) [x86_64-linux]
2015-04-08T20:59:05.711339+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-08 20:59:05] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-04-08T20:59:05.711843+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-08 20:59:05] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=19263
2015-04-08T20:59:07.801064+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=ae843156-0a58-46c1-a337-c622208e558e fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=346ms status=500 bytes=32806
2015-04-08T20:59:08.327653+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=8859d3bb-6a86-45da-814e-2d1400cf7263 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=273
2015-04-08T21:00:12.031263+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails c` by karlneumann61@gmail.com
2015-04-08T21:00:16.316848+00:00 heroku[run.8033]: Starting process with command `rails c`
2015-04-08T21:00:16.273483+00:00 heroku[run.8033]: Awaiting client
2015-04-08T21:00:16.542068+00:00 heroku[run.8033]: State changed from starting to up
2015-04-08T21:00:36.871421+00:00 heroku[run.8033]: State changed from up to complete
2015-04-08T21:00:36.852479+00:00 heroku[run.8033]: Process exited with status 0
2015-04-08T21:00:47.123245+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `irb` by karlneumann61@gmail.com
2015-04-08T21:00:51.870194+00:00 heroku[run.8658]: Starting process with command `irb`
2015-04-08T21:00:51.829253+00:00 heroku[run.8658]: Awaiting client
2015-04-08T21:00:52.244324+00:00 heroku[run.8658]: State changed from starting to up
2015-04-08T21:06:00.169021+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 2fa71a8 by karlneumann61@gmail.com
2015-04-08T21:06:00.169021+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v34 created by karlneumann61@gmail.com
2015-04-08T21:06:00.858341+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-04-08T21:06:03.231028+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788818+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788801+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-08 21:06:03] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788808+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788810+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788812+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788824+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788830+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788836+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-08 21:06:03] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788861+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-08 21:06:03] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-04-08T21:06:03.817499+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-04-08T21:06:03.817506+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.9 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:19263
2015-04-08T21:06:03.817508+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-04-08T21:06:03.817510+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788826+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788828+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788820+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788814+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788815+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788825+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2015-04-08T21:06:03.817512+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-04-08T21:06:03.817514+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788817+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2015-04-08T21:06:03.788822+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2015-04-08T21:06:04.556844+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-04-08T21:06:05.239348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 51743 -e production`
2015-04-08T21:06:09.526524+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-08 21:06:09] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-04-08T21:06:09.526539+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-08 21:06:09] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-02-25) [x86_64-linux]
2015-04-08T21:06:09.526541+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-08 21:06:09] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=51743
2015-04-08T21:06:09.762624+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-04-08T21:06:10.399326+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=02625479-f288-4b5a-8630-4f8c4340825c fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=183ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T21:06:10.582710+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=d88d7ce7-29ae-44c3-9b02-827bccaed693 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=273
2015-04-08T21:06:23.250309+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=42957740-d362-4d01-a6da-228639563cd8 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T21:06:23.424646+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=71b45dc4-83ea-42ea-9116-17b0947bd7b5 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=178
2015-04-08T21:08:26.530796+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=6cecf303-4a4f-491b-ab59-d9fe5869915c fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T21:08:26.703863+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=cea8ee33-7849-4075-b2e2-a4f75888de67 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=178
2015-04-08T21:10:38.775574+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=6ed8b038-7bd4-4a26-aecd-113c82385688 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=42ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T21:10:38.960333+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=3784667c-363e-432e-9afe-3bb550f9fcc6 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=178
2015-04-08T21:13:00.421178+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=a0deb273-a1f2-43db-87b2-c0063c0b0928 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=64ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T21:13:00.649220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=b91eeb87-f6ae-4849-b016-cb6d98331707 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=178
2015-04-08T21:13:33.619183+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=32de7992-e96d-420c-926c-9731b804a109 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T21:13:33.837367+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=c53c3a7c-27f9-47d4-89b2-55e9e7daa5aa fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=178
2015-04-08T21:15:17.622440+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=27b33a42-62b6-4509-8341-6a53e94221c9 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=50ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T21:15:17.844377+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=9f0c60c8-97a2-4628-8a68-587e0a767ce9 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=178
2015-04-08T21:18:35.247221+00:00 heroku[run.8658]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2015-04-08T21:18:35.919623+00:00 heroku[run.8658]: Process exited with status 129
2015-04-08T21:18:35.929423+00:00 heroku[run.8658]: State changed from up to complete
2015-04-08T21:26:49.084292+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by karlneumann61@gmail.com
2015-04-08T21:26:53.500136+00:00 heroku[run.1135]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-04-08T21:26:53.474863+00:00 heroku[run.1135]: Awaiting client
2015-04-08T21:26:53.727200+00:00 heroku[run.1135]: State changed from starting to up
2015-04-08T21:26:59.686281+00:00 heroku[run.1135]: State changed from up to complete
2015-04-08T21:26:59.667354+00:00 heroku[run.1135]: Process exited with status 0
2015-04-08T21:27:22.303972+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=0a1f187b-4af8-4796-848c-228273113f75 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=21ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T21:27:22.476170+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=2c972651-a0f5-40d0-953a-22a98ee31e54 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=178
2015-04-08T21:27:25.116136+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=4ae6b331-98fa-4879-83c5-6a62bdc74d82 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=41ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T21:27:27.273040+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=ba9551d5-c924-4daf-9214-3fe342df7f3f fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=43ms    status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T21:27:30.578930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=043da344-853c-4d75-a5d6-86a94aa44c00 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=42ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T21:41:48.411255+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=45e6f1dd-5b65-4e17-87b9-ed1496584dd7 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T21:41:48.577592+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=a39f9e80-5393-4567-aea2-ee4cc70e04d4 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=178
2015-04-08T21:53:27.984181+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=e1fc42b5-839b-49b3-a393-93d96182f6a0 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T21:53:28.159565+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=69a339f3-379e-45be-a381-c4ed8192d007 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=178
2015-04-08T22:07:17.980998+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=0a54ce03-5edd-417b-8b36-d0c61608a7ff fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=20ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T22:07:18.151149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=3f6cb077-01ae-41a1-a025-38aeb01c5084 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=178
2015-04-08T22:07:37.180779+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=4ccc61a9-b432-42ef-ae44-4c383f2d805a fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=125ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T22:12:04.773961+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=71197215-692d-47f5-b291-ccf01d7386b8 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=61ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T22:15:18.801851+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=8e8c3ad6-dbab-4016-a5bd-6e9a61f27b41 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=1799
2015-04-08T22:15:19.059733+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=d5db82bb-54d1-4eba-b932-c4063a875755 fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=273
2015-04-08T22:20:13.807920+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-meadow-7068.herokuapp.com request_id=68bd0039-8f1f-429e-a5fb-f491d40da09e fwd="68.4.41.5" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=50ms status=500 bytes=1799
```

Here is the GEMFILE:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.1.9'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk','<2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby','~> 3.1.2'
```

Can somebody please take a look and give me some advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many problems with heroku on ruby 2.0. I would try upgrading your ruby to 2.1.2. Remove ur Gemfile.lock and bundle install from scratch. After that make sure you precompile your assets and then push to heroku again.

Answer (score 0):

add this in the group :production of your gem file

```
gem 'rails_12factor'
```

then run bundle install

Answer (score 0):

I needed to drop create and migrate the production database. I got the app online although I am getting errors while trying to populate the db. If necessary, I will create another post for that issue. Thanks for the suggestions.